# Find the $ E(x) $ of $ \frac{1}{x} $

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

A random sample of independent observations $x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n}$ of a distribution:

$f(x) =  \theta^2x e^{- \theta x} $
with  $0  \leq x <  \infty$

consider $\hat{\theta}= \frac{2n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^n{X_{i}}}$ as an estimator for the parameter $\theta$
Consider the particular case of n = 1

1) Find $E(\hat{\theta})$

I most find $E$ of $(\frac{1}{x_{1}})$ but I really do not know how to do it
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Find the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and then calculate the expectation for the general case.

Comment: Can it also be done by integrating the density function multiplied by $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @JazmínJones Yes, by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician